# Why is the well-known sticky footer script the way it is?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

It's well-known, the script on http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/: the **sticky footer** script!

A sticky footer keeps on the bottom of the viewport, unless the content is longer. Beautiful.

But now, here is a script which seems to do the same thing.
The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        (Paste here your content.)
    </div>
    <div id="push"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

div#push {
    height: 32px;
}

div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So if you put the well-known **sticky footer script** in opposite to mine (as above), which should I use? Are there any advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: If they both work, it doesn't matter. I'd use the one that works with the most browsers.

Comment: Your code is nice and simple, but I think it will fail for cross-browser compatability. If you tested it with the major browsers and versions thereof -- use your code :)

Comment: It should be noted that it is a bad idea to use `* {margin:0; padding:0;}`. It is okay for proof of concept code like above, but in live environments it is too overly broad and can make styling things like forms unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @MC-Emperor The difference is that you forgot that min-wight doesn't work in IE6 and IE7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to fail for older versions of IE because they don't support `min-height`. The other code implements a workaround so that it will still work for those browsers. Read the last section of this page http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ about "The `height: auto !important;` and `height: 100%;` properties".

Comment: So the code itself (unregarded older browsers) does work, is valid and is shorter?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It works when I test it in chrome, and I don't notice anything in it that would cause it to fail in any other modern browsers.